# Gitlab CI pipeline for ANT

Tags: ant, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

My Gitlab CI for ANT project is giving Build fail error and also "*Target "HelloWorld" does not exist in the project "null".*" 
I am using "ant clean build" command in script to build the project.
[image]

My build.xml :

```
<project>
<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="bin"/>
</target>

<target name="build">
    <mkdir dir="bin"/>
    <javac srcdir="src" destdir="bin"/>
</target>

<target name="jar">
    <mkdir dir="bin/jar"/>
    <jar destfile="bin/jar/HelloWorld.jar" basedir="bin">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="Main"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="run">
    <java jar="bin/jar/HelloWorld.jar" fork="true"/>
</target>
```

My HelloWorld.Java

```
package javaapplication1;
public class HelloWorld {
public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Hello World");
}
}
```

My folder structure is:

[image]

Can someone let me know how to make this build successful ?

Comment: Can you show your .yml file?